# How to access to the second row of a Datatables footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I would like to add a second `<tr>` to the footer of my datatable in order to display the grand total (after doing some sums).

All the calculations are already working, I just want to inject the value of `rowSum` when `j >= 12` in the 2nd row of the footer.

Concept of the desired result (cropped image):

[image: concept]

This is what I've tried:

1. **✓** Adding a second `<tr>` to the datatable (working)
2. **✗** Inject the value of `rowSum` to the last column of the second row of the footer (I guess I am doing something wrong here)

And this is the part of the code that I think is wrong:

```
$('#example > tfoot  > tr').each(function(index, tr) {
    var rowSum = 0;
    for (let j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
        if (j >= 2) {
            var tdCellValue = numberFromString(tr.cells[j].innerText);
            rowSum = rowSum + tdCellValue;
        }
        if (j >= 11) {
            tr.cells[12].innerText = rowSum;
            tr[1].cells[12].innerText = rowSum;
        }
    }
});
```

Here I tried to access to the second row of the footer: `tr[1].cells[12].innerText = rowSum;` and I think this is where I made the mistake.

[DEMO JS BIN](http://live.datatables.net/vepedopa/21/)

Does anyone know how can I access the second row of the datatable footer and inject the value properly?

Comment: You can achieve this with the "footerCallback" option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your JS code with the following. Here is [Demo](http://live.datatables.net/yekugaxu/1) of the working file.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    
        
        var DT1 = $('#example').DataTable({
    
            columnDefs: [{
                orderable: false,
                className: 'select-checkbox',
                targets: 0,
            }],
            select: {
                style: 'os',
                selector: 'td:first-child'
            },
            order: [
                [1, 'asc']
            ],
            "language": {
                "info": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ Projects",
                "infoEmpty": "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 Projects",
                "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total Projects)"
            },
            "pagingType": "numbers",
            dom: 'rtip',
            initComplete: function(settings, json) {
                // calculate the sum when table is first created:
                doSum();
            }
        });
    
        $('#example').on('draw.dt', function() {
            // re-calculate the sum whenever the table is re-displayed:
            doSum();
        });
        $(".selectAll").on("click", function(e) {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                DT1.rows().select();
            } else {
                DT1.rows().deselect();
            }
        });
        
        // This provides the sum of all records:
        function doSum() {
            // get the DataTables API object:
            var table = $('#example').DataTable();
            // set up the initial (unsummed) data array for the footer row:
            var totals = ['', 'Total:', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
            // iterate all rows - use table.rows( {search: 'applied'} ).data()
            // if you want to sum only filtered (visible) rows:
            totals = table.rows().data()
                // sum the amounts:
                .reduce(function(sum, record) {
                    for (let i = 2; i <= 12; i++) {
                        sum[i] = sum[i] + numberFromString(record[i]);
                    }
                    return sum;
                }, totals);
            // place the sum in the relevant footer cell:
            for (let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
                var column = table.column(i);
                $(column.footer()).html(formatNumber(totals[i]));
            }
            
            
            $('#example > tbody  > tr').each(function(index, tr) { 
         var rowSum=0;
            for(let j=0; j<12; j++)
            {               
                if(j>=2){
                 var tdCellValue=  numberFromString(tr.cells[j].innerText);
                 rowSum=rowSum+tdCellValue;
                }
                if(j >=11){
                 tr.cells[12].innerText=rowSum;          
                }
            }
        });
        var grandTotal=0;
       $('#example > tfoot  > tr').each(function(index, tr) {
              if(index<1){
              grandTotal=0;
                var rowSum = 0;
                for (let j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
                    if (j >= 2) {
                        var tdCellValue = numberFromString(tr.cells[j].innerText);
                        rowSum = rowSum + tdCellValue;
                    }
                    if (j >= 11) {
                        tr.cells[12].innerText = rowSum;                    
                        grandTotal=rowSum;
                    }
                }
              }else{
                 tr.cells[11].innerText = "Grand Total";
                 tr.cells[12].innerText = grandTotal;
              }
            });
        }
    
        function numberFromString(s) {
            return typeof s === 'string' ?
                s.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
                typeof s === 'number' ?
                s : 0;
        }
    
        function formatNumber(n) {
            return n.toLocaleString(); // or whatever you prefer here
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to calculator value of last column, you need get sum of all cells in this row ( not **2 rows** with *$('#example > tfoot  > tr').each* -> in html , you have **2 ***tr***** )

```
$('#example > tfoot  > tr').each(function(index, tr) {
    if (index == 0) {
        var rowSum = 0;
        for (let j = 0; j < totalCol; j++) {
            if (j >= 2 && j < 12) {
                var tdCellValue = numberFromString(tr.cells[j].innerText);
                rowSum = rowSum + tdCellValue;
            }
            if (j >= 12) {
                tr.cells[12].innerText = rowSum;
                //    tr[1].cells[12].innerText = rowSum;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the value is already calculated and 'stored' in `rowSum`, all I need is to inject this value and somehow display it in the second footer row when `j >= 12`